# How to assess consistency of regression coefficients across multiple subsamples

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I'm running a regression on various subsets of data and want to know if the 'b' coefficient has a consistent impact (in terms of size and direction) across these subsets.

```
C1 = a + bX
C2 = a + bX
..
Cn = a + bX
```

What methods can I use to check this when there could be up to 20 subsamples? Is my current approach fundamentally flawed?

Comment: is it just the value of the coefficient you want to assess ?

Comment: @RenaudBied-charreton Yes I want to test the effect of X whether is constant or variable across the different subsamples. what else do you think would be assessed?

Comment: well can't you look at the standard deviation of the "b" coefficient, or run anova based on the caracteristics of the subset ?

Comment: @RenaudBied-charreton Yes, actually I think of the same thing. but do you think this is enough to evaluate the impact of the consistency of the coefficient.